# Finding two adjacent and touching tags, and making CSS changes to them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, formatting

I'm working on a redesign for a site that uses a fairly in depth CMS.  The editors have for a long time simply used a bold tag for headlines, but now we want to add bold text in an article font, and headlines in another font using h3 tags.  But as a legacy work-around, any bold text in new articles are going to appear in the headline font.

The old headlines will always be formatted with a **strong** tag by itself in a **p** tag. Meanwhile, the bold font will naturally be a **strong** tag in a paragraph of text.  The content is wrapped in a **div** with an id named **bodycopy**.

So, as an example:

```
<div id="bodycopy">
    <p><strong>Old style headline</strong></p>
    <p>Here is paragraph text that can contain <strong>bolded</strong> text.</p>
</div>
```

I need a way to style in CSS **strong** tags for the article font, and exact combinations of **p** and **strong** tags as headlines.  Everything I've tried, whether CSS or Javascript/jQuery, has not worked at all.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #bodycopy p strong {font:bold 11pt Arial;}
    #bodycopy p+strong {font:bold 20pt "Times New Roman";} // Doesn't work
</style>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

**Edit:** These headlines can appear anywhere in the text, not just as the first line or paragraph.

Comment: `#bodycopy p strong {font:bold 11pt Arial;}` should work. Do you have a Fiddle to show it isn't working?

Comment: `p+strong` would be for `<p>hello</p><strong>world</strong>`, `p>strong` would be for `<p><strong>Hello World</strong></p>`. Is this what you are having trouble with?

Comment: I assume the headline will be in Times New Roman?

Comment: @MarcAudet For the sake of the example, yes.

Comment: @putvande Technically yes, it does work, but it overwrites the "p+strong" styling as well.  To clarify, I'm basically looking for a way to convert legacy `<p><strong>` styling into what would be `<h3>` styling.

Comment: `p strong {...}` is different to `p + string { .. }`. It styles different objects. You know what the difference is right?

Comment: I just noticed your updated post.  You will need a JavaScript/jQuery solution to enable your styling.  From a CSS point of view, we can't distinguish between the two cases of `p strong` since CSS can't evaluate the content within the tag.  Can you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#bodycopy p:first-child strong {font:bold 20pt "Times New Roman";} 
#bodycopy p strong {font:bold 11pt Arial;}
```

Comment: That would only work if the first <p> with strong should be that format. It sounds like this would work for the legacy pages, but not the new ones that use h3s.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem since the `<strong>` tag in each case is the first child of the `<p>`
tag.

If you are sure that the headline pattern `<p><strong>...</strong></p>` is always the first child of the containing block, you can try:

```
#bodycopy p strong {
    font: bold 11pt Arial;
}
#bodycopy p:first-child strong {
    font: bold 20pt "Times New Roman";
}
```

This will take care of your legacy pages.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/BvB9G/